# Can't update state property? React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am attempting to validate an input manually by passing up the chain the input of a text field. Some magic is supposed to happen whereby the following conditions are checked:

- if input text matches that already held in an array - error = "already exists" & the text isn't added to the list
- if input text is blank - error = "no text input" & the text isn't added to the list
- if input text is not blank and does not already exist - run another method to add text to the list

***The error is set to null by default***

Currently in the input.js file, the {this.props.renderError} line causes an "underfined" output in the console before anything happens. I understand why this occurs, but I wondered if there was any way to stop it?

*Functionality-wise:* I can get the error message to output, however this appears to run after the text is already placed in the list of tasks...

[**Checkout the sandbox for this code**](https://codesandbox.io/s/j3r14mpxjw)

**App.js (parent)**

```
const tasks = [
  { name: 'task1', isComplete: false },
  { name: 'task2', isComplete: true },
  { name: 'task3', isComplete: false },
]

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      error: null,
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Input
          createTask={this.createTask.bind(this)}
          renderError={this.renderError.bind(this)}
          taskList={this.state.tasks}
          throwError={this.throwError.bind(this)}
        />
     </div>
    )
  }

  createTask(task, errorMsg) {
    this.throwError(errorMsg);

    if (this.state.error) {
      return;
    } else {
      this.setState((prevState) => {
        prevState.tasks.push({ name: task, isComplete: false });
        return {
          tasks: prevState.tasks
        }
      })
    }
  }

  throwError(errorMsg) {
    if (errorMsg) {
      this.setState((prevState) => {
        prevState.error = errorMsg;
        return { 
          error: prevState.error 
        }
      })
    }
    return;
  }

  renderError() {
    if (this.state.error) {
      return <div style={{ color: 'red' }}>{this.state.error}</div>
    }
  }
```

**Input.js (child)**

```
render() {
    return (
      <form ref="inputForm" onSubmit={this.handleCreate.bind(this)}>
        <TextField placeholder="Input.js"/>
        <Button type="submit">Click me</Button>
        {this.props.renderError()}
      </form>
    )
  }

  validateInput(taskName) {
    if (!taskName) {
      return '*No task entered';
    } else if (this.props.taskList.find(todo => todo.name.toLowerCase() === taskName.toLowerCase())) {
      return '*Task already exists'
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  handleCreate(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Determine task entered
    var newTask = this.refs.inputForm[0].value;
    // Constant for error message returned
    const validInput = this.validateInput(newTask);
    // If error message produced - trigger error to be shown & end
    if (newTask) {
      this.props.createTask(newTask, validInput);
      this.refs.inputForm.reset();
    }
  }
```

**Update**

I have since found that I can make this work if I move the `renderError` and `throwError` methods to `input.js` and also transfer across the state property `error`.

Comment: Legacy API: String Refs `ref="inputForm"` maybe update it as described in the doc - https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: maybe return an empty string or null as the last in your render method - `renderError() { /*your code*/ return null; `}

Comment: @Kunukn thanks for the advice on Refs.

Comment: I put everything in a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/j3r14mpxjw

Comment: @Kunukn putting a return in the render hasn't done anything :-(
I moved things into the input file itself that seems to work properly... but I would prefer to have things working top down